# Open file in new window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have jquery function which calls an action GetReport which returns a pdf file.
This is the Action
`return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);`

This is the function

```
function showReport() {
    var clinic = $("#SelectedClinic").val();
    var date = $("#SelectedDate").val();
  var url = "/Reports/GetReport";
     $.get(url, { SelectedClinic: clinic, SelectedDate: date }, function (data) {
         $("#outPut").html(data);
     });
}
```

This is the result in the

```
 DIV $("#outPut") 
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] endobj 5 0 obj << /Length 4660 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream X ������wॳ ��K����8�Zo�f剥�,9������d�w�К_���ʶ��t��*�������R��z���7k{`[tUٷm���{��ж����� ;��E=�g}7J��.N~��ގ0Xy'o7���.N�[��W�d��Q���1��u:����U��#�����N�V���t~���7ecwd��=fX��i�7�dj;�i��L���
```

I would ideally like to open the pdf file in a new window or tab.
I might also like to show the file `DIV $("#outPut")` but my real question is how to open it in a new window.

By the way this works

```
@Html.ActionLink("View in new tab","GetReport","Reports", new {SelectedClinic = "Galway"  }, new { target="_blank" })
```

but i cannot set the SelectedClinic parameter without doing a post.

The SelectedClinic should come from the dropdown.

Thanks
Eamon

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ajax get you can use standard javascript window.open function.

Here's more information about this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp